# How to show a 'Done' button in iOS webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, webview, uiwebview

I have a web view that loads local HTML content, which also contains links to PDFs. The PDFs open fine within the web view, except that there's no way to navigate back when you've done with the PDF.

Is there a way of displaying a done/back button when displaying PDFs in a web view?

Any help would be much appreciated, cheers!

Darren

Comment: have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own done/back button and show/enable it only when `[webView canGoBack]` returns `YES`. And in button action call `[webView goBack]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should basically re-size the webView either from top or bottom to create a space for `UIButton` that acts as backButton & implement the visibility of the backButton on condition

```
if([webView canGoBack])
{
 backButton.alpha = 1;
}else {
 backButton.alpha=0;
}
```

& in backbutton target method implementation write the code `[webView goBack]`

Comment: Which would be great, except that as there are multiple HTML files, canGoBack will return true after navigating from the first page. I only need it there when a PDF (and also video) is loaded. I guess I could just load the content in an iFrame in a lightbox.